# Scope for HealthDataTypes of Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I want to read `HealthDataTypes`. Which `Scope` must I set when creating `GoogleApiClient`?

```
.addScope(new Scope(????))
```

Comment: I'm on the same situation,.. just want to read.. did you find any way to do this?

Comment: According to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066595/is-there-google-fit-rest-api-for-reading-blood-pressure-data) it works through the `HistoryApi` (at least via REST, but should be the same), I assume the scope will be the `FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE ` scope? EDIT: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/issues/22

Comment: Yes, I found that and I also get a response from google with all the scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#fitnessv1. I'll see if it works today

Answer (score 2):

Google Fit provides fitness API scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#fitnessv1). It is a list of specific scopes from which you can choose.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#restricted_data_types), Google Fit restricts write access for the data types in HealthDataTypes to only certain developers because health data is potentially sensitive. Apps need user permission to read and write data of a restricted type. Any application can read fitness data of a restricted data type, but only Google-approved applications can write data of this type. If you would like to write to a restricted data type:

1. Send an email to `google-fit-restricted@google.com` and request to be added to the whitelist of apps allowed to write data of a restricted type to Google Fit. Provide a brief description of the data types you would like access to.
2. If the data from your application can originate from connected devices, please include the following details about your use case and connected devices:

   - Data Type(s) to be written to.
   - Device model.
   - Validation Protocols Met (e.g. ESH 2002, BHS, ISO15197:2013).

Comment: I want READ data. 
"Any application can read fitness data of a restricted data type"
"Apps need user permission to read and write data of a restricted type."
user permission - it is `Scope`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the correct answer by myself.. you can create a FittnessOption object using the required data types, and the get the implied scopes for it:

```
GFitUtils.buildFitnessOptions(
            readTypes,
            writeTypes
            ).getImpliedScopes();
```

(where readTypes and writeTypes are lists of DataTypes

in this way, you won't need to harcode the values from the google fit site